# how to convert image to base64 flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hy guys, i'm beginner of flutter, i want to asking some question.
the code below has the function of changing the image path to base64,

```
    _avatar = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: i);
if (_avatar != null) {
  final List<int> _avatarBytes = File(_avatar.path).readAsBytesSync();
  _avatarBase64 = base64Encode(_avatarBytes);
}
```

how to make the image converted to base64 not the path?

Comment: Hi @Shalahudin welcome to SO, the code you have posted is convert the image to 64base encoding, not the file path

Comment: Take a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202639/flutter-how-to-encode-and-decode-audio-files-in-base64-format/60202746#60202746

Comment: but the result is the path and the truth is like in this link https://controlc.com/1eee4786, this is what i want https://controlc.com/2b715497

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your Image in some variable like `var savedImage;` and use below **code**:

```
ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source).then((image) async {
      print(image);
      if (image != null)
        setState(() {
          savedImage = image;
        });
    });
```

```html
List<int> imageBytes = savedImage.readAsBytesSync();
    String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
```

And use this saved image in `FileImage` widget

**`FileImage(savedImage),`**

Comment: What output is coming ?

Comment: this is the actual output https://pasteboard.co/JBY58a3.png

Comment: i want this kind of output https://pasteboard.co/JBY5KvI.png

Comment: did you check your base64 output in https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter base64 to image conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change the image to string :

```
final bytes = Io.File(imageBytes.path).readAsBytesSync();
String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
```

Comment: i think thats not the solution, because it doesnt work