# Play base64 audio file in iOS devices using flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to play audio files in a flutter app. I do have base64 audio files which [AudioPlayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) package can handle in android but is not working in iOS devices. Is there any means i can play base64 audio files in iOS devices using flutter? I have spent hours trying to figure it out but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a answer for this question in Stackoverflow

```
List<int> fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
String base64String = base64Encode(fileBytes);
```

Kindly refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60202639/11789675) for full info

**or you can use this**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class FileConverter {
  static String getBase64FormateFile(String path) {
    File file = File(path);
    print('File is = ' + file.toString());
    List<int> fileInByte = file.readAsBytesSync();
    String fileInBase64 = base64Encode(fileInByte);
    return fileInBase64;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this solution rather converts an audio file to base64 but i want the opposite, that is to convert a base64 audio file to mp3.

Comment: I jsut edited the answer kidly check

Comment: This converts a file to base64, right? I am looking to convert base64 to an mp3 which can be played in iOS.

Comment: Yah bro, it will convert the base64 to mp3 file I think